# Table partitioning takes too long with percona mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-administration, percona

I'm trying to create a new partition (LIST) on an existing table (innodb) with 30million records. the query is running almost 2 hours and it still on "copy to tmp table" state.
I have used the percona mysql performance wizard to improve and I don't see any differences. The server is with no traffic at all. 
Running on Ubuntu server with 16cores, 30GB memory and SSD 300/3000 IO. it looks like the mysql is not using all resources. the memory usage is on 9GB and only 3 cores are running on very low load. 
Is there a way to improve setting to use more resources and speed up the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `PARTITION BY LIST` is virtually useless.  Why do you think it might be worth doing?

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  If there are a lot of secondary indexes, that could be the issue.

How big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Sounds like it is not as big as it should be.  (Recommend about 70% of *available* RAM.)

Let's see the SQL that is taking so long.  There may be something subtle in it.

Comment: Ok, You right. the innodb_buffer_pool_size and tmp_table_size. increased the tmp_table_size to 128mb and innodb_buffer_pool_size to 24GB.. Works good :) thanks